# Geopandas and Geoplot no longer importing after installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, geopandas, fiona

I'm currently trying to reinstall Geopandas as well as Geoplot. The packages were installed previously, and worked fine earlier today. However due to a package limitation I needed to reinstall anaconda completely.

I've tried installing it via the navigator to no avail. looking through previous questions I tried running:

```
conda install geopandas
```

as well as, and for Geoplot

```
conda install geoplot -c conda-forge
```

now when I try importing the packages into Spyder IDE (3.3.3) I receive this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'buffer_to_virtual_file' from 'fiona.ogrext' (unknown location)
```

I figured it may have had something to do with Fiona, so I uninstalled and reinstalled that, as well as update all packages via:

```
 conda update --all
```

At this point I'm lost, installation through the console isn't my strong suit and I'm not entirely sure what options to take next. Let me know if you need me to list anything else.

Comment: create a new environment with the desired packages you want, all from the conda-forge channel. with the GIS stack, mixing conda-forge and the defaults rarely works

Comment: @PaulH You sir are a LIFE. SAVER. it works